# Sharepoint Search Content source

Tags: 2007, search, crawling, search-scope

i have ssp and have 10 content sources which crawl 10 different sites  . . 
suppose i add a new content source . . 
i will add my site link in the content source and do full crawl .
in search result i will be able to find only the results pertaing to my site in content source or i will get all the results from other content sources too ?

Also , how does ur site comes to know that
 it needs to take the particular content source from the SSP . do we need to set somewhere the id of the content source name to ur site ? how does sharepoint work ?

Answer (score 1):

there are two different things you have to configure:

- The first thing are your content sources, they tell SharePoint where to crawl the data.
- The second thing are the "search scopes", they define which content gets queried.

Example:

Content Source 1: www.mycorp.com/USA

Content Source 2: www.mycorp.com/UK

Content Source 3: www.mycorp.com/CANADA

Scope 1: AMERICA

Scope 2: All the world

Scope 1 will then be definded to return results from content sources 1 & 2,

whereas 
Scope 2 will be definded to return results from all content sources.

Comment: You do need scopes, but you need to configure SharePoint to use them as well. Depending upon your requirements you would do this via the Site Settings page or alternatively via your search site. The specific approach is more requirements driven (i.e. maybe you have different pages for different scopes)?

Comment: Yes, Neil is right -good addition. @Getsmiles: Could you already try to do that? Did it work?